# Connect to Mongodb Server remotely via internet?

Tags: java, mongodb

As a mini project of my college i created  a Event Management System application in JAVA and have used Mongodb as a database... My application is ready but now what i want to do is i want to access the database which is stored in my PC (where the Mongodb server is installed) from another PC via the internet... 
I have no Idea how to do this

I can do this in a Local Network but i want to achieve this using Internet so that any device running my application can connect to the DB which is stored in my system (server)

To connect locally i just used

```
MongoClient m=new MongoClient("IP of my system",27017);
```

I was wondering if something like this could be used for connecting via Internet too?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the router of your home network and forward the port your database uses to your local pc, you can.

However, do note that you'll need your external IP address to connect to, not your local network address. And you'll also need to make sure your firewall is configured to allow the port access on your pc.

If you have trouble forwarding the port on your router, here is an article that might help you: http://www.pcworld.com/article/244314/how_to_forward_ports_on_your_router.html (however, a google search containing `port forwarding router` will also get you there)